# Getting errors and I don't know why

Tags: java, compilation, expression

I'm trying to check the grammar of a string.

```
class EMailAdress {

    public static String fname;
    public static String lname;
    public static String org1;
    public static String org2;
    public static String domain;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Out.println("Bitte geben sie eine Email-Adresse ein:");
        fname = In.readIndentifier();
        if (!In.done()) {
            Out.println("fname nicht gelessen");
            return;
        }
        char c1 = In.read();
        if (c1 !== ('.' || '@')) {

            Out.println("@ erwartet");
            return;
        }
        if (c1.equals('.')) {
            lname = In.readIndentifier();
        } else {
            org1 = In.readIndentifier();
            return;
        }
        char c2 = In.read();
        if (c2 !== ".") {
            Out.println(". erwartet");
            return;
        }
        org2 = In.readIndentifier();
        if (!In.done()) {
            domain = In.readIndentifier();
        }
        if (!doman.equals("at" || "com" || "net")) {
            Out.println("at, com, net erwartet");
            return;
        }
        Out.println("Korrekte Email erkannt!");
        Out.println("Name:" + fname + " " + lname);
        Out.println("Organisation:" + org1 + " " + org2);
        Out.println("Email:" + fname + c1 + lname + org1 + c2 + org2 + domain);
    }

}
```

I can't compile this code, and I don't understand why.
`In.readIndentifier` is a method that I can use, so is `in.done`.

Comment: What error are you getting? The message generally gives useful information when things don't compile.

Comment: what is `In` and what is `Out` ?

Comment: they are classes or methods that i can just use
so i can just use Out.println and not System.out.println...

Comment: Replace out with System.out. By the way What is In

Comment: errors like illegal start of expression

Comment: Post the **exact** error message(s)

Comment: cannot find symbol domain or org1 or fname
In.readIndentifier() reads the next word (string)

Answer (score 0):

there are some weird things in your code, not sure what is `In` and `Out`but here is first thing

```
if (c1 !== ('.' || '@'))
```

it should be

```
if (c1 != '.' && c1 !='@')
```

this is another

```
if (c2 !== ".")
```

java is not javascript and for comparsion you are using `==` or `!=`

and one more

```
 if (!doman.equals("at" || "com" || "net")) {
```

`equals` takes object as parameter not hmm... invalid operation
so you need to split it in

```
 if (!(doman.equals("at")&&doman.equals("com")&&doman.equals("new")))
```

and another one

```
char c1 = In.read();
... 
if (c1.equals('.'))
```

`c1` is primitive not Object, so it doesnt have method `equals`

Comment: ok i will correct them
i get errors that i cant find symbols or variables

Comment: hmm now it says it cannot find symbol domain

Comment: @IriBrahimaj  actually `doman` you made typo in that line and i carried it forward

Comment: guys i corrected it, it works now
thank you very much u r the best :D

Comment: well now i can compile it but it doesn't do what i want for it to do...
this is how it looks now:

Comment: class EMailAdress{
public static String fname;
public static String lname;
public static String org1;
public static String org2;
public static String domain;
public static char c1;
public static char c2;

Comment: public static void  main (String[] args){
Out.println("Bitte geben sie eine Email-Adresse ein:");
fname= In.readIdentifier();
if (!In.done()){
Out.println("fname nicht gelessen");
return;
}
c1=In.readChar();
if (c1 != '.' && c1 !='@') {

 Out.println("@ erwartet");
 return;
}
if (c1== ('.')){
lname = In.readIdentifier();
} else {
 org1=In.readIdentifier();
 return;
}
c2=In.readChar();
if (c2!='.' ) {
Out.println(". erwartet");
return;
}

Comment: org2=In.readIdentifier();
 if (!In.done()){
 domain=In.readIdentifier(); 
  } if (!(domain.equals("at") && domain.equals("com") && domain.equals("net"))){
   Out.println("at, com, net erwartet");
   return;
   }
Out.println("Korrekte Email erkannt!");
Out.println("Name:" +fname+ " "+lname);
Out.println("Organisation:"+org1+ " "+org2);
Out.println("Email:" +fname+c1+lname+org1+c2+org2+domain);
}
}

Comment: @IriBrahimaj and what you expect from your program?

Comment: to tell me if the email im righting is correct or not
and where r the errors

Comment: @IriBrahimaj then make your life easier and go with regexp solution

Answer (score 0):

It is the simplier way to validate Strings using **java.util.regex.Pattern**.
You just need to specify pattern for your needs. Here is working example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Runner {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    public Runner() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    }

    public boolean validate(final String email) {

        matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Runner runner = new Runner();
        System.out.println("abc@net.com " + runner.validate("abc@net.com"));
        System.out.println("abcnet.com " + runner.validate("abcnet.com"));
    }
}
```

Here you can find [extra patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)